Do I need to disable Secure Boot to install Ubuntu 24.04?
I have trouble with the installation of Ubuntu 24.04. Apparently it's a problem with Secure Boot. Do I need to disable Secure Boot to install Ubuntu 24.04?
The Ubuntu installer says: ubuntu subiquity_log.3671[19854]: The Secure Boo key you've entered is not valid .The password used must be between 8 and 16 characters.
It's been stuck at the same place for one hour. Yesterday it was stuck for 3 hours before I shut it down.


Your error message at the boot message screen is:
Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will be asked again after a reboot.
The Secure Boot key is not valid.
The password must be between 8 and 16 characters.

Disable Secure Boot, install Ubuntu, and re-enable Secure Boot.
The Secure Boot password you created is persistently stored in the motherboard of the computer. Save the Secure Boot password in a safe place where it won't be lost if something bad happens to the operating system or if you decide to remove or reinstall Ubuntu.

Thanks , that is working .

Plesse click the gray check beside this answer to mark it as accepted. It will turn green when you click it.

This is a bug (as of 2024 May 12):

Installation fails to complete when installing nvidia-driver-550 on 24.04 Beta

You can avoid this issue by not installing third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi. Instead, enable those after installation (search for additional drivers). This way, you do not need to disable secure boot mode.

As pointed out in this answer, disabling secure-boot opens a few doors that you don't want opened.
